# Programatically re-order images in the ACF gallery add-on. Orderby Title, ID, etc

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have a gallery field using the [advanced custom fields gallery addon](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/gallery-field/).

This is how I am outputting my gallery fields/images in my theme...

```
<?php

$images = get_field('gallery');

if( $images ): ?>

    <div id="gallery-1">

        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

And this is the only way in the documentation I can see how to implement it.

Does anyone now who how I can order the images by title, id or anything when they are outputted in the loop?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Php's [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function with a callback. For example, if you want to sort images by ID, you could try something like this (stealing the filter that @Milo used in their answer):

```
<?php
function sort_callback($a,$b)
{
  if ($a['id'] == $b['id']) {
    return 0;
  }
  return ($a['id'] < $b['id']) ? -1 : 1;
}

function my_acf_load_field( $field ){
  usort( $field, 'sort_callback');
  return $field;
}
add_filter( 'acf_load_field-gallery', 'my_acf_load_field' );
```

You can adjust the `sort_callback` function to sort by whichever value in the $image array that you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

see documentation for the [acf_load_field-{$field_name}](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/filters/acf_load_field/) filter:

```
function my_acf_load_field( $field ){
    // sort $field
    return $field;
}
add_filter( 'acf_load_field-gallery', 'my_acf_load_field' );
```

Comment: I'm confused, the documentation does not really explain how to order re-order from the gallery. For example I'm trying to order by $image[title]. I can't envisage how to go about it :/